# special type of first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know a first order ODE has the form
$$x'(t) = f(t,x(t)). \tag{1}$$
where $f$ is a function $f:\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \rightarrow R.$
However, I am dealing with an ODE that has a function as a third argument in the function $f$, i.e.
$$x'(t) = \hat f(t,x(t),g(t,\centerdot)). \tag{2},$$
where $\hat f:\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \mathcal C(\mathbb R \times \mathbb R;  \mathbb R)$ is some operator, $y$ is a variable independent of $x$ and $t$ and $C(\mathbb R \times \mathbb R;  \mathbb R)$ is the space of continuous function from $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.
Is there a way I can use the theorem of existence-and-uniqueness for ODEs of type (1) with my ODE (2)?

Answer (score 1):

When $y$ is fixed, $x'(t) = f(t, x(t), g(t, y))$ is a case of equation (1). If each of these has a unique solution, the only way (2) can have a solution is for the fixed-$y$ solutions to be independent of $y$.

Comment: Sorry, when I read your answer I realized that my question wasn't properly written. The third argument is a function not a number. I rewrote the question again.